# Can an induced current ever increase in the direction in which it is flowing?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction

Suppose B0 is a varying magnetic flux through a surface Σ enclosed by a line. An emf is induced and current flows in the direction of the electric field. The self-inductance is added to the magnetic flux.

Φb = B0 + LI

Hence, if the current through the closed line increases, so does the magnetic flux through the surface.

However, this change in magnetic flux is in the direction opposed to the change in magnetic flux that gave rise to the electric field, which gave rise to the current.

d/dt Φb = d/dt (B0 + LI) = -∫(dΣ) E

From this equation, Φb could only remain changing in the direction needed to support the current if the change in LI was insignificant compared to the change in B0.

However, in a loop dΓ around any cross-section of the conductor:

∫(dΓ) d/dt B = μ0 d/dt I

where B ∝ B0 + LI

If change in LI was not significant enough compared to change in B0 to cancel the induced electric field, it appears that it would also not be significant enough to account for the increasing magnetic loop expected around an increase in current in that direction.

It seems that either current is increasing in the direction of its own flow, or there is an electric field in that direction, but not both at the same time, at least in the case of an induced current. Is this analysis correct, or is there something I am overlooking?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does that not violate the Lenz's law ? Even if $LI$ is not significant, it could behave the same way that the a regular induced current should. For me, there should be a minus sign coming from the integral over $d\Gamma$ between the variation of $I$ and the variation of $B$.

Comment: @HitMan01 In my scenario, the current flows in a loop in the direction of induced electric field. The magnetic field due to this current is opposite to the change in magnetic field which induced electric field, which seems correct with Lenz's law. Ampère: ∫(dΓ) B = μ0 I, differentiate both sides after time (t), there should be no negative sign here.

Answer (score 0):

> where B ∝ B0 + LI

This is not valid. B0 and LI are magnetic fluxes, scalar quantities, numbers. B is a vector of net magnetic field, which is vector sum of external magnetic field and self-induced magnetic field. Self-induced field enhances the external field on one side, and diminishes it on the other side of the wire.

> If change in LI was not significant enough compared to change in B0 to cancel the induced electric field, it appears that it would also not be significant enough to account for the increasing magnetic loop expected around an increase in current in that direction.

I assume by "increasing magnetic loop" you mean increasing magnitude of Ampere loop integral

$$
C = \oint \mathbf B \cdot d\mathbf s.
$$

Magnetic flux $LI$ can be small at the same time the current $I$ is high. There is no need for $LI$ to account for the value of $C$.

> It seems that either current is increasing in the direction of its own flow, or there is an electric field in that direction, but not both at the same time, at least in the case of an induced current.

That makes no sense, and does not follow from above. When current is increasing in direction of its flow, assuming ohmic conductor medium, this implies net induced electric field is increasing in that same direction. So there is both increasing current and increasing induced electric field in that same direction. Only the self-induced electric field (a component of total induced electric field) is opposed to this, because it always opposes change in current.